# javalang.exception:key pair not generated, alias <androiddebugkey> already exists and java.io.filenotfoundexception:debug.keystore

Tags: debugging, android-keystore

I enter the following

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

in cmd to generate debug keytool.

However, I received the error

> java.io.filenotfoundexception:debug.keystore" instead. Afterwhich I changed the above command to "keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\Users\me.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

And this time I received another error

> javalang.exception:key pair not generated, alias  already exists

What goes wrong here? What I am trying to do here is just to generate a new debug keystore.

Comment: anyone any comments or helps?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found out that you need to delete the existing debug.keystore before generating a new debug.keystore. When generating a new debug.keystore, you need to list the directory where you want to store the keystore file.

After delete the old debug keystore, enter the below command in android studio terminal:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore C:\Users\abc\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Where `debug.keystore` is the name you want to define your keystore file, `C:\Users\abc\.android\debug.keystore` is the directory where you want to store the keystore

Comment: im already deleted this *debug.keystore* but when i run the command `.\keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore C:\Users\jit\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` i got this  **Illegal option:  C:\Users\jit\.android\debug.keystore
keytool -genkeypair [OPTION]...

Generates a key pair**

Comment: and he lists all of the options

Answer (score 1):

Based on a suggestion from others, I actually deleted `debug.keystore`, hence the `file not found exception`

Below worked:
- Retrieved debug.keystore back form recycle bin
- Reverted to old keys, instead of new upload keys. The old key was generated using android studio.

Reverted to old key is because play console rejected the upload of new app release as an update to older one.

Answer (score 0):

when you creating next app (you always created one)there was alwasys upload-keystore.jks .so first you have to delete that. then paste your code in terminal

On Mac/Linux, use the following command:

content_copy

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

On Windows, use the following command:

content_copy

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error and what I had to do was to delete the upload-keystore.JKS file from the original path given when creating it the first time and the project itself. For me, I had to delete it from

1. My Project in Android studio

   android/app folder

And also, from my computer

```
/Users/bojack folder
```

A better and easier way is create a folder where to store the file, then add the path just after "-keystore" key word